# R plot - color of entries in dots plots based on presence in other data frame (using loop)

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have two data frames, one contains the categories of individuals, the other contains value of some character, like this:

df1:

```
individuals V1       V2
HG097      -0.0181  -0.0818
HG099      -0.0188  -0.0808
HG100      -0.021   -0.0753
HG101      -0.0196  -0.0804
HG1941     -0.0206   0.0174
HG1942     -0.031    0.0075
HG1944     -0.0291   0.0454
HG1945     -0.0245  -0.0128
HG1947     -0.0184  -0.0065
HG1950      0.006    0.0167
NA18542    -0.0296   0.0899
NA18543    -0.0318   0.1012
NA18544    -0.0305   0.096
NA18545    -0.0317   0.1068
NA18546    -0.0315   0.1016
NA18547    -0.0332   0.098
```

df2:

```
GR1      GR2       GR3        GR4
HG097    HG100     HG1944     NA18543
HG099    HG1941    HG1945     NA18544
HG101    HG1947    NA18542    NA18545
```

Now, while plotting `V1 v.s V2` from `df1`, I want to color the dots based on the group to which its `individual` belongs in `df2`. So, how the loop will be set for this purpose?

```
df1 <- read.table("data_file", header =T)
df2 <- read.table("persons_group_file", header =T)
plot(df1$V1, df1$V2, col=...............)
```

Comment: Why do you have a ggplot2-tag when you don't use ggplot?

Comment: Its ok if the task can be achieved with ggplot2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a loop here, you need `merge` and `melt`. Here's how I would solve it: turn df2 to long format, and then merge with df1. Plotting using ggplot is then straightforward.

Note that not all your individuals have been assigned groups within your example data.

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

#Convert df2 from wide format to long format
mergedat <- melt(df2,measure.vars=colnames(df2))

#Merged the data into df1:
plotdat <- merge(df1, mergedat, by.x="individuals",by.y="value", all.x=T)

#head(plotdat)
# individuals      V1      V2     variable
# 1       HG097 -0.0181 -0.0818      GR1
# 2       HG099 -0.0188 -0.0808      GR1
# 3       HG100 -0.0210 -0.0753      GR2
# 4       HG101 -0.0196 -0.0804      GR1
# 5      HG1941 -0.0206  0.0174      GR2
# 6      HG1942 -0.0310  0.0075     <NA>

#plotting
p1 <- ggplot(plotdat, aes(x=V1,y=V2,color=variable)) + geom_point()
p1
```

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid using a loop to do this.  If you have your data in the correct format it is easy to pass this to ggplot2 to plot.

```
#First do some data wrangling to get data into correct format
#load required libraries
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
#Convert df2 from wide format to long format
tall_df <- tidyr::gather(df2)
#Incorporate that data into df1
merged_df <- dplyr::full_join(df1, tall_df, by = c("individuals" = "value"))
#Then pass this data to ggplot2 to print:
library(ggplot2)
g = ggplot(merged_df, aes(x = V1, y=V2)) + geom_point() + aes(colour = key)
g
```

[image]